# Trying to identify a short story (might be a novelette) about alien abduction and meat consumption

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-abduction

Probably by a British author, because it concerns a group of people who is abducted in the United Kingdom (the narrator is abducted in London). The main theme is the identification of what was the motive for this special group of people to be selected. This motive is that all of them are related to the meat industry/consumption.

In the case of the main character, it's his conscience that we kill animals to provide food to human beings. At the end, the group is left on a planet. Their colony is found some time after, and the main genetical traits are redheadness and slanted eyes. The story was published either by F&SF or IASFM, because I read it in one of them, in the 80s or 90s, in their respective Brazilian editions.

Comment: I don´t remember anything like this in the story. In any case, considering that I read it more than 20 years ago, I can´t be sure about this.

Answer (score -1):

Terry Bisson published *They're made out of meat* in Omni in 1990 about alien machines studying humans and being very confused, I don't think that's quite the one you're after but check it out and see.

It can be read online [here](http://www.terrybisson.com/page6/page6.html).

Comment: The typical suggest answering method is to provide snippets from the suggested text which match descriptions from the question. Could you possibly [edit] your answer to include some? I also hope you don't mind my edits to your answer!

Comment: The story you suggested seems to have very little in common with the plot in the OP's question, there's no plot with a group of people abducted, nothing about the meat industry or animals, and nothing about a colony.  Can you expand a bit more on how or why you think its similar?

Comment: @Megha I haven't read _They're made out of meat_ at all, I don't like the author and refuse to subject myself to anything he wrote, as such I have no idea what's in the plot and I clearly stated that I don't think it's the story the OP is looking for but I have noted here for the OP to check out just it in case it is.

Comment: @Edlothiad That would require me to actually read Terry Bisson, which is not going to happen, once was enough. Your edit is however most welcome I'm not yet completely conversant with the options available to me in terms of hyperlinks etc...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend suggest random stories to ID. We're here to answer the OPs question, not make him search for an answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad It's not random at all, it's the only hit you get when hunting for a story involving Aliens and any discussion of Meat or Meat Workers.

Comment: @Ash I followed the link in the answer and read _They're made out of meat_. It´s not what I´m looking for. Thanks a lot, anyway.

Comment: @nmgsantiago All good I'll keep looking anyway, I'm usually pretty good at the sport of story finding.